# selected date plus 1 week after; result turn out weird issue

Tags: php

**input form:**  html5 date

```
  <strong>  Start Date: </strong>
  <input type="date" name="rentstart" id="rentstart" value="" required/>
```

**POSTING TO RENTAL.PHP**

```
        $lol = $_POST['rentstart'];                                     

        $pDate = strtotime('$lol + 1 week');
        $rentdue=  date('Y-m-d',$pDate);

        insert PDO ETC BLAH BLAH
```

Result of Start date in database:

```
2013-11-01
```

Result of rent due in database:

```
1970-01-01
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `strtotime("$lol + 1 week") or  strtotime($lol .' + 1 week');`

Comment: YAY it worked! thank you. you guys rock.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use :

```
strtotime("$lol + 1 week"); // double quotes
```

Or :

```
strtotime($lol.' + 1 week'); // escaped var
```

[PHP doesn't interpret dollar `$` symbol betwen single quotes.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` would work but in your case the problem is that the string you're passing to it is single quoted (variables are replaced with their values only in double quoted strings) and thus it literally contains `$lol + 1 week`, instead of, say, `2013-11-01 + 1 week`.

You should do one of these:

```
$pDate = "$lol + 1 week";
$pDate = $lol.' + 1 week';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$date = new DateTime($lol);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

for more info:https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function newDate($date)
    {
        $inputDate  =   $date;
        $afterWeek      =   date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+1 week', strtotime($inputDate)));
        return $afterWeek;
    }
```